# Dynamic inclusion of domain name in Firebase hosting

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have an `index.html` file that is published via the Firebase hosting. I have setup a `DEV`(elopement) and `PROD`(uction) app in Firebase console. And successfully linked my own domains to it (https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain)

This page includes opengraph meta data, and as part the `og:url` which should point either to the `mydomain.dev.com` (when published to `DEV`) or `mydomain.prod.com` (when published to `PROD`). I do not want to start duplicating the `index.html` file (code maintentabiliy) so how can I dynamically insert the correct domain via Firebase Hosting?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>    
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta property="og:url" content="mydomain.dev.com or mydomain.prod.com">
 <meta property="og:type" content="website" />  
 <meta property="og:title" content="Some title" />
 <meta property="og:description" content="some description" />      
 <meta property="og:image" content="/assets/img/og.jpg" />
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can handle this.

1) Build step before deploy

Have a single index.html template file that contains variables.

```
<meta property="og:url" content="{{domain}}">
```

You then use a build tool like [gulp](https://github.com/carlosl/gulp-nunjucks-render) or [webpack](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin) to replace the `domain` variable with the domain of the particular site you are deploying.

2) Function rendering

This will have a similar index.html template that lives in a [Firebase Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events). You then map your hosting to be backed by Function which will render the HTML with the correct domain on request.

Comment: Option 1 looks interesting (option 2 would cause to many function invocations = cost). Can this be integrated in vscode somehow?

Comment: Function responses are routed through Hosting so you can [set the cache](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions#set_cache-control) for as long as you wont. That way you will get minimal function invocations and mostly just hosting usage.